# Track history across repositories

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have an application that was moved from one repository to a second in mid-development.  For contractual reasons this was done by copying the most recent version of the source from the old repository into the new repository as the initial version instead of importing the complete history to the new one.

This mostly hasn't been a problem since people with access to both can go to the old one to get history from before the migration; but I'm wondering if there's a way we could configure tortise to continue tracing history from the new to the old repository if the user has access to both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be nice to have, but I doubt it's possible.

Most SCMs' notion of history, Subversion's included, is bounded by the limits of the repository.  Having a broader sense of history would be possible, but I don't know of any SCMs that do.  A front-end like TortoiseSVN might opt to hack the feature in, but it seems like it would have a pretty limited audience.

The right thing to do would be to move the entire repo over, and there are various ways to do that, but if you're contractually obliged not to do that...

Sounds like more of a contract problem than a technical issue.

Comment: I figured it was a longshot at best.  We'd need to sanitize every one of the thousand+ checkins to bring them over; and that's prohibitively time consuming.  If I remember the timeline right the contractual issue didn't bite until after we started development.  Going forward we've architected it to keep stuff that needs locked in NDA compartments separate and bring it in at build time, but there's not much we can do for all the older work.